# Redis Pipeline is taking time if called parallely

Tags: python, redis

Currently i am using the following python code to ingest huge data into redis. It is able to insert 10000
records per 50 sec(which is not that fast).But if i run this function paralelly for two different data sets its taking almost 4 minutes to insert 10000 records.

Currently Redis is installed on server and i am executing this python script by deploying it in my local machine .Is the slowness due to executing this script from my local machine which means deploying it on server will increase the speed.

Also can you please let me know is approach of loading data into redis is good or is there a better way to insert huge data into redis.

In the below function. batch size is configured 10000(i.e for every 10000 records call pipeline.execute)

```
def load_hashmap(data, client, keycolumn, batchsize):
    try:
        pipe = client.pipeline(transaction=False)
        n = 0

        for row in data:
            pipe.hmset(row.get(keycolumn), row)
            n = n + 1

            if len(data) < batchsize and n == len(data):
                pipe.execute()
                print("Data Load Batch--" + str(n) + " completed at " + str(datetime.now()))

            if (n % batchsize) == 0:
                pipe.execute()
                print("Data Load Batch--" + str(n) + " completed at " + str(datetime.now()))
                pipe = client.pipeline()

        if len(data) > batchsize and (n % batchsize) != 0:
            pipe.execute()
            print("Data Load Batch--" + str(n) + " completed at " + str(datetime.now()))

    except Exception as e:
        raise Exception(str(e))
```

Answer (score 0):

First of all,

You can use  **HMSET(or HSET) myhash field1 "Hello" field2 "World"**

to insert several key/value at onces. So no need for pipeline.

You need to check the network I/O usage, and I would bet that running the script on a computer within the same network of the Redis instance would help. (network I/O is the most common bottleneck of redis performance)

Comment: Thanks for the inputs